# how to show textviews on the left and imageview on the right side?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I am developing android app and I want to show full texts on the left side and imageview on the right side but textviews not fitting all screen and imageview not showing at all

below my xml where I have implemented view logic with constrainlayout
below my xml where I have implemented view logic with constrainlayout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.55" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/postImage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userId"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Placeholder"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/postTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Secondary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/postImage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/userId"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/userId" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/postTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Tertiary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/userId"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/postTitle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/postDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Tertiary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/userId"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/postTime" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: imagefrom device]

Comment: Please provide some image of what you want to achieve

Comment: Post any image to show what do you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline"` to your `TextView`. Check below Layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.55" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/postImage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userId"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Placeholder"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/postTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Secondary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/userId"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/userId" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/postTime"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Tertiary"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/userId"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/postTitle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/postDescription"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Tertiary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/userId"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/postTime" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]

With `android:justificationMode="inter_word"` to `TextView`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Placeholder"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Secondary"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/postImage"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/userId"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/userId" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Tertiary"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/userId"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/postTitle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Tertiary"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/userId"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/postTime" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/postImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```